# Path in a Modified Preorder Tree Traversal

Tags: php, mysql, algorithm

I've implemented a Modified Preorder Tree Traversal [as explained here](http://www.sitepoint.com/hierarchical-data-database-2/). My tree is something like this:

```
+-------+-----------+-----+-----+
| ref   | name      | lft | rgt |
+-------+-----------+-----+-----+
|  NULL | base      |   1 |   8 | 
|     2 | basic     |   2 |   3 | 
|  NULL | listener  |   4 |   7 | 
|     1 | test      |   5 |   6 | 
+-------+-----------+-----+-----+
```

Everything is ok, but now I tried to implement a PHP search function based on a path, it is, something like this:

```
$result = searchTree('base.listener.test');
// Now $result is an array with node {1, test}
```

It means that searchTree returns a subtree based on the path given. If the path doesn't exists it will return an empty array.

My current implementation is a recycled function that loads the tree into a PHP array and then it splits the path and walks through the array. It seems a non-scalable implementation... Any better implementation (perhaps using a mySQL query?).

My current implementation is like this. First I get the whole tree (SELECT * FROM tree) and then I execute this function to make a multidimensional array from this data:

```
function create_tree($results) {
    $return = $results[0];
    array_shift($results);

    if ($return['lft'] + 1 == $return['rgt'])
        $return['leaf'] = true;
    else {
        foreach ($results as $key => $result) {
            if ($result['lft'] > $return['rgt'])
                break;
            if ($rgt > $result['lft'])
                continue;
            $return['children'][] = create_tree(array_values($results));
            foreach ($results as $child_key => $child) {
                if ($child['rgt'] < $result['rgt'])
                    unset($results[$child_key]);
            }
            $rgt = $result['rgt'];
            unset($results[$key]);
        }
    }

    unset($return['lft'],$return['rgt']);
    return $return;
}
```

Then I have an array in *$tree* variable and execute this piece of code:

```
$t3 = $tree;
$parts = explode('.', $path);
while (isset($parts[0]) && count($parts) > 1 && isset($t3['children']) && $parts[0] == $t3['name']) {
    array_shift($parts);
    for ($i = 0;  $i < count($tree['children']) && $tree['children'][$i]['name'] != $parts[0];  $i++);
    $t3 = $tree['children'][$i];
}

return isset($t3) && count($parts) == 1 && $parts[0] == $t3['name']? $t3['children'] : array();
```

The last line returns the node pointed by the $path (i.e. 'base.listener.test') or an empty array if this path doesn't exists.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're looking for, you want to call:

```
$result = searchTree('test');
```

and get search the database for the parents?

```
SELECT p.name
    FROM tree c
    INNER JOIN tree p ON p.lft < c.lft AND p.rgt > c.rgt
    WHERE c.name = 'test'
    ORDER BY p.lft;
```

Comment: No, sorry. I explained very bad... (question edited). searchTree() returns a multidimensional PHP array with the corresponding subtree. I.e. if you ask for "base.listener.test" it returns a simple array with the node 'test'. If somebody asks for 'test' it will no return any result because there is no root element called 'test'. If somebody asks for 'base' it will return an array with all base children: [basic, listener[test]]

Comment: So, are you looking for a better way to populate the array? Or a way to use the tree without creating the array?

Comment: A better way to populate the array, because I believe my method is not very scalable (now I have 100 items in the tree, but I expect to have about 10.000)

Comment: In order to give you a _better_ way, it would be necessary to see the _current_ method used. Can you show the contents of the `searchTree` function?

Comment: I've updated the question. Note that it isn't a full implementation, but I believe it's easy to understand.