# PHP Nested Set - Multidimensional array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array, nested-sets

So I've been searching for a good way to implement nested categories in mysql and stumbled upon this article:

```
http://falsinsoft.blogspot.com/2013/01/tree-in-sql-database-nested-set-model.html
```

Now I'm struggling with generating the nested array. I need to generate an array that looks like this

```
Array
(
   [0] => Array
   (
      [id] => 1,
      [name] => Electronics
      [children] => Array
      (
          [0] => Array
          (
              [id] => 2,
              [name] => Televisions
              [children] => Array (...)
          )
      )
   )
   [1] => Array
   (
      [id] => 5,
      [name] => Another Parent category
      [children] => Array
      (
          [0] => Array
          (
              [id] => 6,
              [name] => Child category
              [children] => Array (...)
          )
      )
   )
)
```

There is already a solution to this problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7276935/path-in-a-modified-preorder-tree-traversal) but the function doesn't work with multiple root categories. The other root categories simply get ignored.

```
function create_tree($results) {
    $return = $results[0];
    array_shift($results);

    if ($return['lft'] + 1 == $return['rgt'])
        $return['leaf'] = true;
    else {
        foreach ($results as $key => $result) {
            if ($result['lft'] > $return['rgt'])
                break;
            if ($rgt > $result['lft'])
                continue;
            $return['children'][] = create_tree(array_values($results));
            foreach ($results as $child_key => $child) {
                if ($child['rgt'] < $result['rgt'])
                    unset($results[$child_key]);
            }
            $rgt = $result['rgt'];
            unset($results[$key]);
        }
    }

    unset($return['lft'],$return['rgt']);
    return $return;
}
```

@user3508721

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [title] => ELECTRONICS
            [description] => 
            [lft] => 1
            [rgt] => 20
            [depth] => 0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [title] => TELEVISIONS
            [description] => 
            [lft] => 2
            [rgt] => 9
            [depth] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [title] => TUBE
            [description] => 
            [lft] => 3
            [rgt] => 4
            [depth] => 2
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [title] => LCD
            [description] => 
            [lft] => 5
            [rgt] => 6
            [depth] => 2
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5
            [title] => PLASMA
            [description] => 
            [lft] => 7
            [rgt] => 8
            [depth] => 2
        )
    [5] => Array
    (
        [id] => 12
        [title] => Parent
        [description] => 
        [lft] => 21
        [rgt] => 24
        [depth] => 0
    )

[6] => Array
    (
        [id] => 14
        [title] => Child
        [description] => 
        [lft] => 22
        [rgt] => 23
        [depth] => 1
    )
)
```

Comment: You need to show code that you have tried.

Comment: Show income data (raw array from db).